# How to release excel file after reading from it in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, file, dispose

The following code is to open excel file and read from it , I want to dispose the excel file to be able to delete it :

```
        Dim strNewPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedExcel/" & strFileName & strFileType)

        'Connection String to Excel Workbook
        If strFileType.Trim = ".xls" Then
            connString2 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strNewPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
        ElseIf strFileType.Trim = ".xlsx" Then
            connString2 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strNewPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
        End If
        query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"

        'Create the connection object 
        conn2 = New OleDbConnection(connString2)
        'Open connection
        If conn2.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn2.Open()
        'Create the command object
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, conn2)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        ds = New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "Staff")

        '    up.insertExcel(ds)

        da.Dispose()
```

Comment: Have you tried `Using conn2 = New OleDbConnection...`?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`Using-Statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) for everything that implements `IDisposable`:

```
Using conn2 = New OleDbConnection(connString2)
    conn2.Open()
    Using  cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, conn2)
        Using da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            ds = New DataSet()
            da.Fill(ds, "Staff")
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

That ensures that the object is disposed (even in case of an exception). `Dispose` also closes connections implicitely.

Answer (score 0):

Beware that Command and Connection classes also implement IDisposable interface.
You should use a "using" block or try/finally statement. In the finally block you must dispose your objects, even in the case some exception arise.

Answer (score 0):

You've failed to call:

```
conn2.Close();
```

(or the equivalent `conn2.Dispose()`)

Which you should do by wrapping in a [`Using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statement, so that it's closed even if an exception is thrown:

```
Using conn2 = New OleDbConnection(...)

    ...

End Using ' conn2 is automatically disposed / closed here
```

Comment: @How to use Using statement ?